# How to include projects in personal SCM repositories (not in pypi) to setup.py?

Tags: python, build, distutils, setup.py, pypi

What's the idiomatic way to build python projects that depend on projects in other source control repositories (e.g private projects not on pypi)?

Let's say I have a project `foobar` hosted at `https://example.com/foobar.git` and I want to include it in the `setup.py` of another project.

Is there something similar to maven's scm plugin, where I can specify something like `Extension('foobar', scm='scm:git:https://example.com/foobar.git')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify additional places to install dependencies from using the `dependency_links` option:

```
setup(
    ...
    dependency_links=[
        'git+https://example.com/spamneggs/foobar.git#egg=foobar-1.2.3'
    ]
    install_requires=[
        'foobar',
    ]
)
```

The `dependency_links` entry is used to find packages, and for SCM-stored packages the `#egg=package-version` fragment identifier lets tools know what package and what version will be found at that link.

See the ["Dependencies that aren’t in PyPI" chapter](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) of the setuptools project documentation.